# php script not showing through my ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I have a index.php file which uses ajax for loading contents from another .php file within the same directory. But for some reason when you click a link from the menu and it is loaded in the ajax, the php script from the news panel isn't executing, or it isn't visible.

**Demo Link**: http://www.michaeldylanedwards.co.uk/#archives

**Direct Link**: http://www.michaeldylanedwards.co.uk/archives.php

**php script**

```
<?PHP
    $category = "8";
    $template = "Archives";
    include("admin/show_news.php");
?>
```

Here is the codes for the ajax loaded content;

**load_page.php**

```
<?php

if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = $_POST['page'];

if(file_exists($page.'.php'))
echo file_get_contents($page.'.php');

else echo 'There is no such page!';
?>
```

**script.js**

```
var default_content="";

$(document).ready(function(){

    checkURL();
    $('ul li a').click(function (e){

            checkURL(this.hash);

    });

    //filling in the default content
    default_content = $('#pageContent').html();


    setInterval("checkURL()",250);

});

var lasturl="";

function checkURL(hash)
{
    if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;

    if(hash != lasturl)
    {
        lasturl=hash;

        // FIX - if we've used the history buttons to return to the homepage,
        // fill the pageContent with the default_content

        if(hash=="")
        $('#pageContent').html(default_content);

        else
        loadPage(hash);
    }
}


function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#','');

    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: {page: url},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So, when on the #archives page its blank, clicking around on the top links #home, #blog etc work, which im assuming is expected behaviour.

However, when clicking on #contact and #social, it breaks the site.. This is because whatever `ajaxpage()` function is doing (you haven't included it in the above JS) is removing the `#pageContent` that the `loadPage()` function requires to insert your content.

(I believe the `ajaxpage()` is just whacking it's response output into the content, which is removing the inner `#pageContent`)

Comment: Morning, I would have suggested to swap out the second argument in your  ajaxpage() function to use "pageContent" over "content". Just had a look now and it looks like it's all working by using the ajaxpage() on all the links, which is much better!

Comment: oh i've changed it back to what it previous was!
what i really want is to be able to send links of each page but not changing the header or footer, but when i do for ajax loaded content it doesnt allow php through it :/

Comment: Ah, sorry. PHP is server side so it'll need to be rendered there first, and then include that in your response data.